# Sending notification to specific device from Lambda Function

Tags: lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

Well, the question is self explinatory. After googling, I found that it can be done. The idea is to create an attribute as part of user profile that will store endpoint ARN. Inside Lambda function, I will need to call AWS cognito API providing username to get the associated endpointern value. Then publish message to the endpointern. Here's my question :

- What Cognito API is available inside Lambda function to retrieve a particular attribute by providing username

Comment: If we are talking about the Lambda functions provided by Cognito, all attributes should be available inside. If we are talking about other lambda functions, you would need to use the node.js SDK and authenticate the user and retrieve the user attributes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node

Comment: Nope. I need to do from S3. Whenever I get new file in S3 bucket, I want to send notification to particular user base on the filename.

Comment: In that case the second approach suggested by Ionut should work for you. You would need to configure S3 events and then do the user related actions in Lambda function. The API to get the user details is AdminGetUser (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html)